# Jasmine 2.0 SpecRunner vs Karma

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I just started using Jasmine and I was able to use the SpecRunner from the Html just fine. However when I configured Karma I encountered a discrepancy:

```
describe('Calculator', function(){
    var obj;
    beforeEach(function(){
        //initialize object
        obj = new Object();

        this.addMatchers({
            toBeFive: function () {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, expected) {
                        return {
                            pass: actual === 5,
                            message: actual + ' is not exactly 5'
                        }
                    }
                };
            },
```

This piece of code does not work from the SpecRunner.html:

```
 this.addMatchers({
```

Instead I had to use this:

```
 jasmine.addMatchers({
```

This is what is include the specrunner:

```
 <!-- libs... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../calculator/calculator.js"></script>

  <!-- test files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/calculator/calculator-test.js"></script>
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addMatchers'
```

Please note that Karma raise no errors but if I use  jasmine.addMatchers({ it does.

Comment: Jasmine normally set the  this object for its own spec runners. Perhaps karma is hijacking that value. Unfortunately I haven't started using karma yet, so I don't really know if this is the case. Have you resolve this issue since last month?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run `npm install karma-jasmine@~0.2.1` after installing karma this will use the correct jasmine version (karma still hasn't updated to install the right version by default as the new adapter was only released a few days ago)

Comment: 6 month later it still provides 0.1.5 by default ... Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 4):

See this document https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/7204OS_The_Future_Jasmine_2_0.pdf

2.0 breaks the way we do matchers

> New syntax to create custom matchers Jasmine 2.0 comes with a new way
>   of creating custom matchers. A lot of refactoring  has been done under
>   the hood, and the most important change is that internally  Jasmine
>   uses this same infrastructure to create its own built-in matchers.

Here is the new way of doing it.

```
jasmine.Expectation.addMatchers({
    toBeAGoodInvestment: function() {
        return {
            compare: function (actual) {
            var pass = actual.isGood();
            var what = pass ? 'bad' : 'good';
                return {
                    pass: pass,
                    message: 'Expected investment to be a '+ what +' investment'
                };
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the version of Karma, the karma-jasmine plugin and jasmine itself? Does your version of Karma/Karma-Jasmine work with Jasmine 2.0.0?

Answer (score 4):

I checked Jasmine documentation site and I understand there are some important differences between 1.3 and 2.0 being one of those the way we declare matchers:

Based on this documentation (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html) there is nothing wrong with:

```
jasmine.addMatchers({
            toBeFive: function () {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, expected) {
                        return {
                            pass: actual === 5,
                            message: actual + ' is not exactly 5'
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
```

The issue is that karma is still running jasmine 1.3.1.

This is how I checked the version of Jasmine I was running:

- In my computer node packages are install under (windows directory):
- `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-jasmine\lib`:
- open jasmine.js

```
    jasmine.version_ = {
                "major": 1,
                "minor": 3,
                "build": 1,
                "revision": 1354556913
            };
```

I found that there are efforts in adapting karma to work with Jasmine 2.0.0:

https://github.com/r-park/karma-jasmine2-test