# Using the Angular Seed Project Unable to Run Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, twitter-bootstrap, jasmine

**Updated**

I am going through the karma modules looking for code that says chrome and trying to switch to firefox unsuccessfully, if anybody knows where I should look too I will be very happy as well.

---

I hope somebody is familiar with angular seed. I wrote a small angular js web app and I wanted to write some tests for it so I was learning jasmine and karma today. I found out that angular seed has these libraries installed, I spent the day moving my project to angular seed.

I am having trouble running the unit tests, I am getting the error below

```
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.4) ERROR
    Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery
```

The funny thing is when I started the server, and in chrome dev console the jquery files are actually loaded correctly on my network and I made sure they came BEFORE bootstrap.min.js

In my index.html file I have these scripts on the bottom

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>       
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

before the end of the body

The site is up and running, there are no errors on chrome developer console.

The angular seed came with a package.json file ( I am suppose to run npm install to install the modules inside the angular seed directory )

I included jquery and got the jquery modules installed anyway, that was my second try.

```
"jquery" : "~2.1.0-rc1"
```

I even went to download the jquery uncompressed file and linked to it in my index.html from my  js/vendor folder. I unlinked it already. The files still exist in my js/vendor folder.

I am getting the error above after running this

```
scripts/test.sh
```

it may be a chrome issue, I am not too sure. I will see if I can switch to testing with firefox. any help or ideas of troubleshooting this issue is appreciated.

if it helps here is my controllersSpec.js file

```
'use strict';

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */

describe('RootPage', function(){
  var rootCtrl; 
  beforeEach(module("backpageApp"))
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
    rootCtrl = $controller("RootCtrl"); 
  }))

  describe("RootCtrl", function() {
    it("should have listings", function() {
        expect(rootCtrl.listings).toBe(true)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list the test dependencies in the karma config file. If you look at the contents of /scripts/test.sh, you can see all it does is this..

```
$BASE_DIR/../node_modules/karma/bin/karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/karma.conf.js $*
```

..so it calls the karma start script and passes it the karma.conf.js. Open the karma.conf.js file and you can see the dependencies shipped with the angular seed project. jQuery is not there as it is not required with Angular, but your application needs it. You should add your bootstrap.js file there as well...

```
 files : [
  'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
  'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
],
```

I would download the jquery file, so you can point to a local copy. For example...

```
 files : [
  'app/lib/jquery/jquery.js',
  'js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
  'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
  'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have followed all the steps yet but in any case these are the steps to run Angular-Karma-Jasmine:

1. You need to install [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/), karma runs on top of node
2. You need to install karma from [Node Packaged Modules](https://npmjs.org/) from your command window execute:

   ```
   npm install -g karma
   ```
3. If you plan to run this with Chrome and Firefox and you are running this on windows you need to add 2 [environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
   CHROME_BIN = [Crome installation path/chrome.exe]
   FIREFOX_BIN =[Firefox installation path/firefox.exe]
```

4. Go back to your project folder using the command window once there you can execute:

```
karma init
```

Just hit enter until it finishes; bottom line this will create a file named:

```
karma.config.js
```

In my project this file looks like this, yours probably will include some helpful comments on the different settings:

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({    
        basePath: '',    
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],    
        files: [
          '../app/*.js',
          '../app/lib/angular.js',
          '../app/lib/angular-route.min.js',
          '../app/lib/angular-mocks.js',         
          '../app/app.js',
          'controllers/*.js',
          'services/*.js',
        ],    
        exclude: [
        ],    
        reporters: ['progress'],    
        port: 9876,    
        colors: true,    
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,    
        autoWatch: true,    
        browsers: ['Chrome','Firefox'],
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        singleRun: false
      });
    };
```

**Important:** make sure you included angular-mocks in your configuration, the `inject` function is on that module.

5. Go back to your command window, navigate where your `karma.config.js` file is and and execute:

```
karma start
```

**Warning:** Karma version downloaded before Jan 21st 2014 uses jasmine 1.3.1 if you included a more recent version of jasmine (maybe 2.0.0) in your project probably you will find [some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20884438/1959948) between that version and the one used by karma-jasmine.

At this point you will be good to go.

About running jasmine from the the from SpecRunner file there may be some differences but I guess that can be topic for another question.